# Can't install laravel in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Im having a problem in installing laravel on my terminal i already installed the composer without a problem but when i [This is what i alwys get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjmsr.png)

Comment: i can't find my config.json

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you duplicate things or during installation in Ubuntu 16.04.
Here is a link that will solve your problem [fix composer error "Content-Length Mismatch"](https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/112f68e5b91a7dac7641bcd8b0ab13ac)

Comment: i can't find my config.json is it ok if i remove the composer and install it again ?

Comment: use command composer update I think it'll fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here to steps to follow](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

All steps given in thisblog